# How do I use CSS.escape() or equivalent for all browsers?

Tags: javascript, html, css, internet-explorer, safari

I have an id for an element that is '#*lK36*kW63*x1*t1510689412121569' or something similar in runtime.

CSS.escape works when I'm running this in Chrome and Firefox. However, it doesn't work (as the doc says) for IE or Safari or Edge.

Is there a convenient function/hack I can use to make CSS.escape(str) work in all browsers?

Comment: https://github.com/mathiasbynens/CSS.escape is one of a few polyfills out there.

Comment: `I have an id for an element that is ... or something similar` What benefit can possibly be in such a cryptic ID? `CSS.escape`, and the structure of the string, says that this "ID" is composed from some properties at runtime, and not defined by a dev. So instead of creating such a weird ID and passing that around to the codes that need to "find" this object, why don't you pass the object itself around? Without any id at all.

Comment: @Thomas he might not be the one creating those ID's that he would still need escaped

Answer (score 2):

Credit to @epascarello for posting this (albeit in the comments)

You can download the polyfill from here https://github.com/mathiasbynens/CSS.escape that will allow you to use `CSS.escape('#*lK36*kW63*x1*t1510689412121569')` in all browsers.

Note though that this also escapes the pound/hash sign at the beginning. I'm not sure if that's part of the ID itself or that's the selector for the ID that follows, but it's important to keep that in mind.